# Why does this simple JQuery code throw an error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        for(var i=0;i<7; i++){
            var guy_html = '<div class="aname"><input type="text" class="chatter_input autofriend" name="guy'+String(i) + '" /></div>';
            $("div#guy_boxes").append(guy_html);
        }
    });
</script>

<div id="guy_boxes"></div>
```

I just want 7 input boxes created and put into the div.

```
Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #
```

Comment: I don't see an issue. Which line does it have issue with?

Comment: Hmm... http://jsfiddle.net/9jXkE/ seems to work OK.

Comment: Which browser are you using ?

Comment: I would omit the tag name. Selecting by ID is more efficient, tag#Id will traverse looking for the tags first, and then traverse the results looking for the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Syntax error, unrecognized expression` is an error that gets thrown by Sizzle (jQuery's selection engine) when you have a poorly constructed selector.  Getting it to trip over a `#` can happen if it comes at the end of your selector:

```
$("div#").append(guy_html);
```

However, your code looks okay.  You may want to check other sections of javascript.

Answer (score 1):

just ran this through jsfiddle and it works fine and without errors :)
http://jsfiddle.net/vM4qU/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you did this in another part of the code

```
#("selector")
```

instead of

```
$("selector")
```

That would throw the error you described.

Comment: It's an easy mistake. The two keys are right next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't this part of code, because it's working fine [here](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/d4a9c). You should search in different snippets of your code